# Is it possible to have types automatically populated in a .js file from an adjacent manually written d.ts file? (as an alternative to JSDoc)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to use manually written `.d.ts` files that are adjacent to the target `.js` file to populate types *within* that file (not just for consumers importing it)?

The desire is to find a better featured alternative to JSDoc types written inline for cases where a project is progressively being migrated to TypeScript or is otherwise exclusively written in JavaScript and incorporating the TypeScript toolchain is impractical.

It's expected to only provide code hints within the IDE and not involve `tsc` for type checking. Simply a development experience enhancement - like JSDoc

For example:

```js
// preload-asset-type.d.ts
export type PreloadAssetType = typeof PreloadAssetType[keyof typeof PreloadAssetType];
export declare const PreloadAssetType: Readonly<{
    Script: 'script';
    Style: 'style';
}>;
```

```js
// preload-asset-type.js
const PreloadAssetType = Object.freeze({
    Script: 'script',
    Style: 'style',
});

module.exports.PreloadAssetType = PreloadAssetType;
```

Types are available for consumers importing that file:

```js
// ./consumer.js
const { PreloadAssetType } = require('./preload-asset-type') // has types
```

However within the `./preload-asset-type.js` file, `PreloadAssetType` does not inherit the associated type defined in the `./preload-asset-type.d.ts` file - meaning there isn't usable type checking within the file.

One solution I have investigated is combining JSDoc with typing files, for example:

```js
// ./preload-asset-type.js
// @ts-check

/** @type {typeof import('./preload-asset-type').PreloadAssetType} */
const PreloadAssetType = Object.freeze({
    Script: 'script',
    Style: 'style',
});

module.exports.PreloadAssetType = PreloadAssetType;
```

This is cumbersome as it requires every variable to have its type shuttled across but it works in simple cases.

However, it falls apart in cases like class definitions where nothing is inherited from the type definition - limiting the type checking for features like generics, etc.

```js
// ./preload-asset.d.ts
export type PreloadAssetOptions = {
    encoding?: PreloadEncodingType;
    rel?: PreloadRelType;
    url?: string;
    type?: PreloadAssetType;
};

export declare class PreloadAsset {
    encoding?: PreloadEncodingType;
    rel?: PreloadRelType;
    url?: string;
    type?: PreloadAssetType;
    constructor(options?: PreloadAssetOptions);
}
```

```js
// ./preload-asset.js

//...

/** @type {typeof import('./preload-asset').PreloadAsset} */
class PreloadAsset {
    constructor(options = {}) {                        // options has no type
        this.encoding = options.encoding || undefined; // encoding has no type
        this.rel = options.rel || undefined;           // rel has no type
        this.url = options.url || undefined;           // url has no type
        this.type = options.type || undefined;         // type has no type
    }
}

//...
```

Is there a way for types to automatically be defined/inherited inside a `.js` file that has an adjacent `d.ts` file - without the addition of JSDoc to shuttle types over?

Example Repo: https://github.com/alshdavid/js-doc-alternative/tree/main

Comment: I got no answer, but I like this as an idea and alternative to jsdoc